# Background Music Stop/Mute on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background-music

I'm creating my first app. I have an app with music playing in the background with the following code:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //background Music
    func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
            return
        }
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }

    }

    playBackgroundMusic("Starship.wav")
}
```

So what should I do in order to stop/mute the background music when I switch to another ViewController? Should I do this my **FirstViewController** or **SecondViewController**?

Obviously, I don't want the sound to be off in the **SecondViewController** as I have other stuff that will be playing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mute sound I simply mute the volume.

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 0
```

and set it to normal if I want sound

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.volume = 1
```

If you just want to pause music you can call

```
backgroundMusicPlayer.pause()
```

To resume you call

```
 backgroundMusicPlayer.resume()
```

If you want to stop music and reset it to the beginning you say this

```
 backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
 backgroundMusicPlayer.currentTime = 0        
 backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

Did you also consider putting your music into a singleton class so its easier to play music in your different viewControllers.

Not sure this is what you are looking for as your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Totally what I looked for. Not sure what it means to put it in a singleton. I'm new to app making. 

To make more clear what I make. 
It's a music app, where in the menu it has to play background music, but once you move on to music "tab" there should be no background cause the possibility to start a music playlist will happen. hope it makes sense. But the answer you gave me, was very helpfull

Comment: Hey, you are welcome. A singleton basically means that you create a class that only exits once. So you can access the same class in multiple view controllers etc without having to put your music code all over the place. Music is a good example of where a singleton class is useful. To get a better  idea you can check my gitHub helper. https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-Music-Helper